# How to disable the python log `URL being requested` `Refreshing access_token`

Tags: python, logging

I have a python code downloading files from google drive by googleapiclient API. The python code uses logger to print information. I set the basic log level to be INFO. However, there is some logger info from calling the API. To be specific, the other and unwanted logger info is: 
`2019-02-12 03:52:21,269 INFO     URL being requested:`
`2019-02-12 03:52:21,091 INFO     Starting new HTTP connection`
`2019-02-12 03:52:19,691 INFO     Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token`
From what I googled, `logging.getLogger("requests").setLevel(logging.WARNING)` seems able to mute the logging info of `Starting new HTTP connection`. But how can I mute the other two?

Answer (score 5):

Grepping through my virtual environment, I was able to see that it's the `googleapiclient` library that's creating the logger. You can mute those messages with

```
logging.getLogger("googleapiclient.discovery").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Or at the module level

```
logging.getLogger("googleapiclient").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```